# How to convert .xls file which has html tags in it to delimited .csv from command line

Tags: linux, excel, xlsx, xls, format-conversion

We have a requirement to download the export from jira portal and insert this information to a table for some reporting. now the challenge is , the file downloaded from jira is in .xlx extension and has all the html links in it. when i use the xls2csv (catdoc software )and other converter tools over the command line they cant recognize the file format and not able to convert. I need this file to be converted as .csv file with some delimiter that way i can use sql loader to load it to a table.
 [image]

Comment: Is your "xlx" (xlsx?, xls?) file really a native excel file, or is it HTML served up with an Excel header?

Comment: I think even the extension of it is "xls" it must be a html or xml.

Comment: Seems like a good first step would be to confirm which exact format your source is in?

Comment: The file exported by JIRA is actually a html renamed as xls. But when i open it in Excel and then save as CSV with delimiter it is working fine. But i need process from the command line to automate the process.

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a tool/library which is capable of parsing HTML content, and use that to convert the download to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `libreoffice` installed on your system, running the following code on a `bash` terminal (as a normal user, not `root` - see the reason [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)) might help you:

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to csv my_file.xls
```

If you need this code to be run on a script that runs as `root`, it would still be possible to (safely) run this command if you run it as a "normal" user instead of `root`, such as:

```
su - myuser -c 'libreoffice --invisible --convert-to csv my_file.xls'
```

To find out who is the `user` who should be used to run the command above, one of the best options would be to use the `logname` command, such as:

```
myuser="$(logname 2>/dev/null)"
```

Comment: I never used LibreOffice, can you point me out to software download location and it's installation process.

Comment: It should be available directly from most `Linux` repositories. This would work on many `Linux` distributions: `apt-get update && apt-get -y install libreoffice`. If that does not work, which `Linux` distribution do you use?

Comment: apt-get not working for me.Linux  2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 27 15:55:46 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:        6.5
Codename:       Santiago

Comment: You might want to check this https://access.redhat.com/solutions/197993 and/or this  https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Install/Linux

Comment: I have one more question here , The below command convers to csv with comma delimited , how do we convert with Tab delimiter instead.                                            
libreoffice5.2  --headless --convert-to csv /data/infa_shared/DQ/Scripts/test.xls --outdir /data/infa_shared/DQ/Scripts/

Comment: Not sure that you can do it directly. But you can transform `xls` into comma delimited first and then run a `sed` command to change the commas into tabs, such as: `sed 's/,/\t/g' file_comma.csv > file_tab.csv`